# In React Admin, How to disable the selection of a reference input?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In React Admin, How to disable the selection of a reference input?

```
<ReferenceInput label="Post" source="post_id" reference="posts">
  <SelectInput optionText="id" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it as below:

```
<ReferenceInput label="Post" source="post_id" reference="posts">
  <SelectInput optionText="id" disabled />
</ReferenceInput>
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#disabled), you can use the *disabled* property on React-Admin input components, including `ReferenceInput`:

```
<ReferenceInput label="Post" source="post_id" reference="posts">
  <SelectInput optionText="id" disabled />
</ReferenceInput>
```

You could alternatively set it to a boolean:

```
… disabled=true />
```

Or you could set it to a function that returns a boolean. This is often useful as you could set it to disable the field based on some logic:

```
… disabled={someFunction} />
```